# fluid simulation does not start

Tags: fluid-simulation

I set everything up correctly (I compared it on YouTube), but the particles do not appear. I attach the file (I brought everything related to the simulation to a separate collection). I would be grateful if someone answers. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mInt4pvlpNCq8WjVbo8Ea9WjXhuHY1bm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your hole bigger and set your resolution to 300 you will start seeing water:

[image]

[image]

maybe first move your inflow outside of your other object so that it is "free" in the domain without obstacles, so you can check whether the resolution is ok now. If water is coming, move the inflow back into your "hole". If it doesn't come out, you know that your "hole" is too small. So you can know whether your geometry is the problem or your resolution.